# Why Doesn't My String In My Vector Change Value?

Tags: c++

I am trying to change the value of time in my vector of structs. The result should output 1430 as the value of shares[1].time though I get something different.

The shares is the name of my vector, I've already populated vector with values for each struct.
Share is a struct which contains a string time.

```
//This is in the Share.cpp
vector<Share>shares  //vector of structs.

unsigned convTime = 1430;
std::stringstream out;

out << convTime;    //make convTime a string stream
shares[1].time = out.str();    


std::cout << shares[1].time;



struct Share
{
    //member all the information in the structure
    std::string date;
    std::string time;
    double price;
    double volume;
    double value;
    std::string condition; //not nessesary in this assignment
};
```

But my shares[1].time stays as its original value and not 1430. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Create an actual self-contained test case with `main()`, etc. It is likely that you will find the problem during the making of the test case.

Comment: When you say different what exactly are you getting?

Comment: [Not reproducible](http://ideone.com/WPAJ3O).

Comment: My output is 14:30:22 though I want to make that value 1430 (24 hr time).

Comment: This is not your real code. Post your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually put objects in the vector before using them. When you write:

```
vector<Share> shares;
```

there are no objects in it yet. Going

```
shares[1].time
```

causes undefined behaviour. If you use the `.at()` function instead of `[]` then you get an exception instead of undefined behaviour.

To put objects in the vector, either use `push_back()`, or `shares.resize(num_objects)`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have defined `vector<Share> shares` in Share.cpp, as you say, *but also somewhere else* !

This violates the One Definition Rule. Weird things may happen as a result. One of the things that definitely could happen is that `shares[1]` in one file isn't the same as `shares[1]` in another. You'd have two variables with the same name. But, remember that this is a *could happen*. Violating the One Definition Rule may break your program in all kinds of unexpected ways.